# Drupal Slideshow rendering 0x0 in grid layout

Tags: drupal, slideshow, drupal-8

I have used the Views Slideshow module on many D8 sites, but have never come across this particular quirk before. On [this site](https://nemasters.adminskiracing.com), the slideshow view in the front page splash screen briefly renders at the correct size but then instantly resizes (each individual `<img>`) to 0x0 shortly after page load (indicating to me that it is likely caused by a JS script somewhere in the module.)

I have dived into the various module folders but so far have been unable to put my finger on where this behavior is coming from. My suspicion is that it could be related to the fact that the Slideshow is located in one pane of a flexible CSS Grid, since I know Slideshow does something on page load akin to calculating the rendered size of each image as it would appear on screen, and that could mess it up. Another slideshow is located lower on the same page outside that grid and is working exactly as expected.

Any help investigating this strange disappearing behavior would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When views slideshow runs it's javascript, it needs the containing div to have some sizes set.
Try adding this so the sideshow takes on the size of the containing div (which is the grid item):

```
.block-views-blockslideshow-header-block-1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This was it!  Just adding an explicit width to the Slideshow container solved the issue.  Turns out if the container's width is determined by a grid layout only (such as 1fr 1fr) it breaks the Slideshow's ability to determine its rendered width. Thanks!